# While loop not breaking when it should

Tags: while-loop, arduino

For some reason the while loop only ends when the end of the string has been reached.

```cpp
while (s.charAt(i) != '_' || s.charAt(i) != ' ') {
  Serial.println(s.charAt(i));
  Next_Char += s.charAt(i);
  i ++;
  Serial.println(Next_Char);
  Serial.println(i);
  if (i == s.length()) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: what was your input?

Answer (score 1):

`while (s.charAt(i) != '_' || s.charAt(i) != ' ')` condition will always fulfill. I think it should be `while (s.charAt(i) != '_' && s.charAt(i) != ' ')`

For example, suppose `s.charAt(i)='_'` here your first condition is now false but your second condition `s.charAt(i)!=' '` this became true so loop will continue even when first condition is false. Hence `while loop` only ends when the end of the string has been reached.

Comment: The problem is that the condition is always fulfilled not never.

Comment: @gre_gor, true I have corrected my answer. Actually my never fulfill meaning was that reason for the condition is not going to fulfill :-) Thanks anyway.